# combined coffee and js development with Gulp

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gulp, gulp-concat

Using Gulp to streamline my build process on a per-save basis, while eliminating the need for "temp" files is my goal (and why I chose to use Gulp over Grunt)

I've recently discovered that, apparently, the coffeescript compiler cannot handle dealing with basic Javascript as a source

So this, errors out:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {

    var stream =
            gulp.src([
                "bower_components/d3/d3.js",
                "bower_components/angular/angular.js",
                "bower_components/foundation/js/foundation.js",
                "public-dev/scripts/app.js",
                "public-dev/scripts/**/*.js",
                "public-dev/scripts/**/*.coffee"
            ])
                .pipe(coffee())
                .pipe(concat('compiled.js'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/scripts'))
        ;

    return stream;
});
```

This produces the output/errpr:

```
[11:58:51] Starting 'scripts'...

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
/var/www/node.fortiguard.dev/bower_components/d3/d3.js:1:2: error: reserved word "function"
!function() {
 ^
```

How should I set this up, without again creating any temp files?

What I liked about the LESS compiler, is that it can still be fed straight CSS files and it'd be fine. I was kind of hoping the Coffee compiler would react the same way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, it doesn't. What you can do, is using the underlying `event-stream`'s `merge` method. Then you'll have one pipeline for the `coffee` files that gets compiled and one for the javascript side.

Here is an example `Gulpfile.coffee`:

```
coffee = require 'gulp-coffee'
es     = require 'event-stream'

gulp.task 'scripts', () ->
  es.merge(
    gulp.src(["public-dev/app.js", "public-dev/scripts/**/*.js"]) # ...
    gulp.src("public-dev/**/*.coffee").pipe coffee()
    )
  .pipe concat 'all.js'
  .pipe gulp.dest "build"
```

Comment: While this does work, it seems to be .. doing it out of order.. some of my angular stuff ive been converting to coffee, gets shunted to the top of the concated file..

Answer (score 2):

I use `gulp-add-src` to do that.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    coffee = require('gulp-coffee'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    addsrc = require('gulp-add-src');

// Scripts
gulp.task('coffee', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/coffee/**/*.coffee')
    .pipe(coffee())
    .pipe(addsrc('src/coffee/lib/*.js'))
    .pipe(concat('compiled.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I marked Patrick J. S.'s answer as "Correct" becuase in reality, this is exactly what I needed to do.

That said, "event-stream" isn't what I ended up going with, simply because I needed to preserve my dependency structure of files, and `event-stream`'s `merge()` method does not preserver order nor does it have options to.

Instead I opted for a package called [streamqueue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/streamqueue), which does preserve order of glob. Probably slower, but order matters in my app unfortunately.  In the future I will try to be as modular as possible.